# Use a Audio tag that works in every browser

Tags: html, html5-audio

So I am getting into HTML5, and succeeded in creating a video **compatible with every browser**. (By simply giving it multiple sources)

Since the audio and video element have a lot of similarities I tried to do the same with the audio element. Like this:

```
        <audio controls="controls" preload="auto">
            <source src="s/audiomp3.mp3" type='audio/mpeg; codecs="mp3"'/><%-- Chrome --%>
            <source src="s/audioogg.ogg" type='audio/ogg; codecs="vorbis"'><%-- Chrome & Opera --%>
            <source src="s/audiomp4.mp4" type='audio/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.5"'><%-- Chrome --%>
            <source src="s/audiowav.wav" type='audio/wav; codecs="1"'><%-- Chrome --%>
        </audio>
```

Does someone see what the problem is, or maybe if there is a way to solve something about this piece of code? Using the video tag I can do about the same thing and get the videos to work in every browser I have here.

I have searched for this, but **only found js fallback libraries**, and that's not what I'm searching for.

Or is that the only solution? Simply implementing js/flash fallback in each browser where they don't accept the extensions?

Edit: Please note that the comments are for ASP.net, so ignore them. These are the browsers in which they work at the moment. Out of the 5 I'm testing, it's just too little.

Edit: Browsers are as follows (all on windows xp): chrome, firefox, Opera, Safari. And IE, but that one isn't part of this question.

Comment: By "compatible with every browser" I'm going to have to assume that you're completely ignoring IE and any other browser that doesn't support the tag itself.

Comment: thats right, im just focussing on making the tag work in the browsers which support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use SoundManager2: http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

Comment: When i have it working, i will mark this as final answer. Till then i am open to other solutions. After a couple hours of trying i didnt get it to work in my asp website. Mostly because the image wasnt clickable, but i will keep trying)

Comment: Im still working on it, but figured out enough to know this might be the solution to my question. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you require compatibility with IE 7 & 8 you should use a third party library. But if not - keep it simple. You only need to use [mp3 and ogg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_Audio) to cover all the major browsers.

```
<audio controls="controls">
    <source src="s/audioogg.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
    <source src="s/audiomp3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
</audio>
```

More importantly, make sure your web server is configured to use the correct MIME types when serving ogg and mp3 files (audio/ogg and audio/mpeg). Without that step, the audio will fail on some browsers.

Comment: It depends on what version of IIS you are using, but generally you just do it through the Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager. The instructions are the same for doing it locally as for a production server: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608(v=ws.10).aspx